# I am getting error while Running Angular application

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap-calendar

I have installed ngx Bootstrap into my Angular Application to use date picker

Now I am getting error while running the Angular Application

I am putting the details of the error below

> ERROR in multi ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   ../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css
>   ./src/styles.css
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/Projects/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
>   in '/Users/user/Projects/CRUD'
>       ERROR in multi ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   ../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css
>   ./src/styles.css
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/Projects/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css'
>   in '/Users/user/Projects/CRUD'

**I am putting angular.json file code below**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "CRUD": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/CRUD",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "CRUD:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "CRUD:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "CRUD:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "CRUD-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "CRUD:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "CRUD:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "CRUD"
}
```

**Package.json code - :**

```
{
  "name": "crud",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: import bootstrap.min.css and bs-datepicker.css direct in html file. remove from angular.json file.

Comment: Hi, if the solution proposed by @AmbujKhanna doesn't work, please post your package.json or angular.json and the Module where you are importing

Comment: If above solution doesn't work then you can try to import both CSS after "style.css" in your angular.json file.

Comment: @AmbujKhanna  Did you import all dependent module in app.module?

Comment: @rick hello I am uploaded the package.json and angular.json  kindly look into it

Comment: @AmbujKhanna yes

Comment: @AnuragRanjan Please keep style.css at 1st position and then list down other css files

Comment: Have you tried rerun of `npm install`? IME this works about 60% of the time. As long as you got component.ts Imports and app.module.ts imports / declarations correct it should work. If it doesnt, triple check these, paying attention for any compile-time errors that are blending in and then rerun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `css` files from wrong location.

update the `angular.json` file:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.

```
Inside .angular-cli.json file
```

> "styles": [
>           "styles.css",
>           "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"   ]

Remove "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Step 2.

```
Go to styles.css
```

Import bootstrap by adding this line

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

These steps solved the errors I got during the building process.

Comment: I am still getting error , I have uploaded the package.json and angular.json code , Kindly look into it

Comment: Please change the sequence of CSS files."styles": [
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the line `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` from angular.json file. This will fix your error.

This line is for bootstrap.

When you remove this line, you will lose that better front end look provided by bootstrap.

If you want to continue to experience bootstrap also, Please install bootstrap first.

to install bootstrap, fire this command in your terminal `npm install bootstrap --save`

then change the angular.json as follow

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
     "styles.css"]
```

It's important to keep the bootstrap file in the top in styles array list.

Hope everything is okay. Cheer coding :)

Comment: He is trying to KEEP bootstrap. that is the whole thing, no?